# how do i disable key repeat in Windows mobile or MC67

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I'm using Motorola [MC67](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC67) with Windows Mobile 6.0 and writing in c# compact framework.

I want to disable the key repeats, so if you press long "enter" for example, i won't get more then one "enter" press. I've searched the Motorola manual, and tried the advice given [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f322f80-1dba-477e-a77e-d667e8f2031f/keyboard-repeat-rate), doing:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKCU\ControlPanel\Keybd", "RepeatRate", "1000000");
```

but with no use.

Can anyone help me?

Just to be clear: I have access to change registry from my code, but even after i change the rate to max possible, it ignore the value in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this key is a software button, you can disable the button:

```
private void btnOK_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  btnOK.Enabled = false;
  try {
    // Your code here
  } finally {
    btnOK.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

If this is for a physical key on your device, I don't really know how to go in and set the "click rate" (or whatever it is called), but you could try adding a `lock` around your routine.

```
private object m_lock = new object();

private void textbox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  lock (m_lock) {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

I don't know if that would help or not, though. I can't test, because my devices here do not seem to have that same issue.

Comment: thank you jp2code, but if i'll do this, i'll have to do it to every form i build, or for every control, and this isn't a new project, it's a 10 years old project being moved to support MC67... a lot of work, but it'll be a good last resort. thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

The hardware keyboard may not care about the registry settings, the hardware drivers are OEM specific.

The RepeatRate is a) much to high (outside specs), b) will take place after a reboot first, c) may control the Software keyboard only.

Here is a long thread that finally comes to a IOCtl solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f322f80-1dba-477e-a77e-d667e8f2031f/keyboard-repeat-rate.

Comment: thank you josef, even though it did not helped and i already posted this link in my question :) thanks for the effort anyway

Comment: So, you have read: "Delay before first delay - MIN: 250, MAX: 1000 (InitialDelay)
Repeat rate - MIN: 0, MAX: 30 (RepeatRate)

If repeat rate is set in CP to 0 it won't repeat in CP icon selection with standard keyboard or d-pad, so it must be it." and then use 10000 as repeatrate?! The repeat is disabled if you set the RepeatRate to 0. Did you also try the IOCtl?